# Need to speedup PERL script(Takes 1 sec for every Row to input)

Tags: mysql, perl

This Perl script below that takes 1 sec per row to insert, which makes it quite inefficient when there are a lot of rows to be inserted. If the input file has over 1,000,000 rows, this script will take approx. 12 days to insert.

Sample Data(Rows)

```
/mnt/SYN/TEST-Dropbox/Documents/TempBM/10-07-19.docx
/mnt/SYN/CLIENT-DROPBOX-GSUITE/Dropbox-TEST/My Mac (TEST-iMac-Pro.local)/Documents/TempBM/10-07-19.docx

/mnt/SYN/TEST-Dropbox/Documents/TO BE TRANSCRIBED LATER/LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, Tape 2 (Inaudible)/LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, TAPE 2 SIDE B (Inaudible).mp3
/mnt/SYN/CLIENT-SYNOLOGY/A. TO BE TRANSCRIBED/*TO BE TRANSCRIBED LATER/LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, Tape 2 (Inaudible)/LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, TAPE 2 SIDE B (Inaudible).mp3
/mnt/SYN/CLIENT-SYNOLOGY/DropboxBackup/*TO BE TRANSCRIBED LATER/LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, Tape 2 (Inaudible)/LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, TAPE 2 SIDE B (Inaudible).mp3
/mnt/SYN/CLIENT-DROPBOX-GSUITE/Dropbox-TEST/My Mac (TEST-iMac-Pro.local)/Documents/TO BE TRANSCRIBED LATER/LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, Tape 2 (Inaudible)/LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, TAPE 2 SIDE B (Inaudible).mp3
```

Script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
use DBI;

my $inputfile = shift || "-1";
my $startline = shift || "-1";
my $endline = shift || "-1";

if (($inputfile eq "-1") || ($startline eq "-1") || ($endline eq "-1") ){
        print "USAGE: $0 <name_of_file.txt> START_LINE_NUMBER END_LINE_NUMBER\n";
}

my $group_id = 1;
my $linecounter = 0;
my $dsn = "DBI:MariaDB:Potato1";
my $username = "root";
my $password = "";

my %attr = ( PrintError=>1, RaiseError=>1);
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password, \%attr);
print "Connected to MYSQL database";

my $sql = "INSERT INTO GMCfiles_tbl(file_id, file_add_date, group_id, filename, status, status_author, status_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
my $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
open(INFILE, "< $inputfile") or die "Could NOT open $inputfile";

while(<INFILE>) {
    my $data = $_;
    $linecounter++;
        if (length($data) < 5) {
            $group_id++;
            sleep 2;
        } else {
            my $file_add_date = DateTime->now;
            my $filename = $data;
            my $status = "New";
            my $status_author="";
            my $status_date = DateTime->now;

            if ( ($linecounter >= $startline) && ($linecounter <= $endline) ) {
                if ($stmt->execute($linecounter, $file_add_date, $group_id, $filename, $status, $status_author, $status_date)){
                    print "Row inserted successfully LINE $linecounter -- GROUP $group_id\n";
                }
                if ( ($linecounter > 0) && (($linecounter % 10) == 0) ) {
                    print "We're processing LINE $linecounter\n";
                }
            }
        }
}

close(INFILE);
$stmt->finish();
$dbh->disconnect;
```

As this script will run for days. Can someone point out a way to increase efficiency?

Comment: Wrap all the inserts in a single transaction?

Comment: [`DBIx::Connector`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector) is a nice wrapper for transaction management, or just use DBI `begin_work()` and `commit()` methods.

Comment: Micro optimization: You don't need to create two different `DateTime` objects in your loop. Or those `$status` and `$status_author` variables when the values assigned to them never change. Use literals or hoist them outside the loop.

Comment: Try running your program with the execute() method call commented out. That will tell you whether the problem is at the perl end or the DB end. On first glance there's no way that script should take a second per row.

Comment: You have a line `sleep 2` in your code. That will make your program wait 2 seconds for ever line in your input file that is shorter than 5 characters (including newline). Are you unaware of that?

Answer (score 6):

This problem appears to have a trivial solution. You have this in your code:

```
if (length($data) < 5) {
    $group_id++;
    sleep 2;
```

The function [sleep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep) will sleep (wait, pause) the number of seconds given as argument. In your case, 2 seconds. This applies to all lines shorter than 5 characters, given the if-clause.

Remove the `sleep` and see if that solves your problem.